# Unable to create a fluent APIs because the type `self` doesn't match `&mut self`

Tags: rust

In many other languages it's common to have APIs that go something like

```
obj.do_x()
   .do_y()
```

In Rust I run into a problem, if `do_x`, `do_y` take `&mut self`, the types don't match. Is there an elegant way to solve this?

For example:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Counter { count: u32 }
impl Counter {
    fn incr(&mut self) -> &mut Counter { 
        self.count = self.count + 1; 
        self 
    }

    fn new() -> Counter {
        Counter {
            count: 0
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, `new()` returns a `Counter`, but the fluent API needs `mut Counter`.

Comment: You'll need to show an actual example of what you've tried for us to show you why its not working. This is common in Rust though.. and people refer to it as the "Builder Pattern". As a random example, here's one I just found Googling: https://gist.github.com/Nogbit/aa0ac67e7208850b94e2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why would you use a reference?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Counter { count: u32 }

impl Counter {
    fn incr(mut self) -> Counter { 
        self.count = self.count + 1; 
        self 
    }

    fn new() -> Counter {
        Counter {
            count: 0
        }
    }
}
```

If you consume the original, then there is no borrow issue any longer :)

*Note: while appropriate for a builder pattern, it may be annoying with regular types.*

Comment: I considered this.. but wasn't sure exactly what the OP was after. +1 anyway - this is the _actual_ way to fix the immediate problem.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Not too sure either, but since it's an oddball compared to the current mainstream languages I thought it worth mentioning :)

Comment: hmm, wouldn't this lead to a lot of copies? Or is rust smarter than that?

Comment: @jz87: From a language point of view, no. It is however lowered as `memcpy` at the moment, and the optimiser might not be smart enough to remove them (case by case basis). pcwalton is working on LLVM to more aggressively remove useless `memcpy` calls, and had a first patch that removed ~25% of the `memcpy` calls in Servo (which is impressive, since probably a number of them ARE useful)... however in review it was suggested that he moved this analysis elsewhere, and while it slows down the integration it may actually improve the number of elided call sites.

Answer (score 10):

You're correct, the types differ. You'll probably run in to lifetime issue. I assume you tried this:

```
let mut counter = Counter::new().incr().incr();
```

That fails. However, splitting them out:

```
let mut counter = Counter::new();
counter.incr().incr();
```

..works fine. The compiler will actually give you a decent hint here:

```
help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

As I said in my comment.. to "work around" this fluent API design during object instantiation, people will commonly create a `Builder` type (the "Builder Pattern"). Yours, for example, might look like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Counter { count: u32 }

struct CounterBuilder { count: u32 }
impl CounterBuilder {
    fn new() -> CounterBuilder {
        CounterBuilder {
            count: 0
        }
    }

    fn incr(&mut self) -> &mut CounterBuilder { 
        self.count = self.count + 1; 
        self 
    }

    fn build(&self) -> Counter {
        Counter {
            count: self.count
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let counter = CounterBuilder::new()
        .incr()
        .incr()
        .build();

    println!("Counter value is: {}", counter.count); // Should print 2
    assert_eq!(2, counter.count);
}
```

Essentially, this works around the lifetime issues by discarding the borrow after the `build` call (its noting that you're finished with an instance of a `CounterBuilder`)... at which point you have a new concrete `Counter` object constructed and ready to go.

Once you have your `Counter` instantiated... you can then modify it via its own fluent API if you want.. e.g:

```
let mut counter = CounterBuilder::new()
        .incr()
        .incr()
        .build();

counter.local_increment().local_increment(); // For example, if you were to add a "local_increment" fluent method to Counter
```